# Sort data in MongoDB on the basis of date embedded in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have my mongodb document as:

```
{
  "_id":"fnbgfbmkgmbkgmbklhn",
  "data":[
      {
         "item":"ITEM1",
         "date":ISODate("2016-09-06T13:38:44.714Z")
      },
      {
         "item":"ITEM2",
         "date":ISODate("2016-09-06T13:50:44.714Z")
      },
      {
         "item":"ITEM3",
         "date":ISODate("2016-09-06T13:45:44.714Z")
      }
  ]
}
```

This document is the result of **db.collectionName.aggregate(....).** After applying aggregate, how the sorting can be done on the basis of "date".

Comment: Can you show us the previous aggregation pipeline which gives the above result? From the marked possible dupe, you can simply inrtoduce a [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) pipeline before the pipeline that gives you that result, so it would be great if you could edit your question to show the full pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could unwind the `data` array, sort the result by `data.date` and group it again by `_id`:

```
[
    {$unwind: {path: "$data"}},
    {$sort: {"data.date": -1}},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", data: {$push: {item: "$data.item", date: "$data.date"}}}}
]
```

It could be more efficient to incorporate these stages into your existing aggregation pipeline instead of just appending them.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help.